# Viewbag from controller (JsonResult) to razor view as hidden field

Tags: json, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

I have the controller function that returns a Json and in side the function I am also populating a viewbag, this viewbag value I want to pass it through to the view as a hidden field which I am not too sure how.

Controller Function:

```
   public JsonResult Person(string name, string Lastname)
        {
            User user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] as User;
            bool moreResults = false;
            string response = string.Empty;
            Index model = new Index();

            Collection<ListItem> results = new Collection<ListItem>();

            try
            {
                if (user == null)
                    return Json(new { faultType = NotificationType.Denied.ToString(), responseText = string.Empty, responseAction = "window.top.location.reload(true);", resultsList = string.Empty }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                Tuple<LogisFault, Collection<ListItem>> lookupResponse = Lookups.GetPersonList(name, Lastname);
                results = lookupResponse.Item2;

                if (lookupResponse.Item1.Message.StartsWith("MORE"))
                {
                    moreResults = true;
                    response = lookupResponse.Item1.Message.Split('-')[1].Trim();
                    return Json(new { faultType = NotificationType.Success.ToString(), responseText = response, hasMoreResults = moreResults, responseAction = string.Empty, resultsList = results }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

                if (lookupResponse.Item1.FaultType == NotificationType.Warning)
                {
                    string action = Notifications.CreatePopupNotification(lookupResponse.Item1.Message, NotificationType.Warning);
                    return Json(new { faultType = NotificationType.Warning.ToString(), responseText = lookupResponse.Item1.Message, hasMoreResults = moreResults, responseAction = action, resultsList = results }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                ViewBag.CanUserEdit = Security.ValidationMethods.CanUserEdit();
                ViewBag.AllowLink = Security.ValidationMethods.AllowLink();

                return Json(new { faultType = NotificationType.Success.ToString(), responseText = string.Empty, hasMoreResults = moreResults, responseAction = string.Empty, resultsList = results }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }}
```

View hidden field returns as empty string

```
<input type="hidden" name="canUserEdit" id="canUserEdit" value="@ViewBag.CanUserEdit" />
```

What I want to do is to save that viewbag value to a hidden field on the view and use the hidden field on my external JavaScript file

Comment: And how json that you get from action can create  a hidden field? Can you post the whole code pls?

Comment: `ViewBag` should be set in the action which render this view.  But from your code, Person action return json instead of view. So you can't pass data from person action to view via viewbag. could you provide more details to show which action render this view and what's the useful of person action?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I have just added `CanUserEdit`  and `AllowLink`  on my model and from there I saved it as a hidden field on my razor view so that I can use it on my external JavaScript file. thank you everyone.